# Remove Object from C++ list

Tags: c++, list

I'm new at C++... I'm making some classes - one for Student and one for Courses. There is an "list" inside of Courses that adds Student Objects.

I am able to add a student:

```
void Course::addStudent(Student student)
{
    classList.push_back(student); 
}
```

But when I go to delete a Student, I'm not able to remove it. I'm getting a long error about Student not be derived and something about the operator==(const allocator).

```
void Course::dropStudent(Student student)
{
     classList.remove(student); 
}
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!!

I was referring to this website for how to add/remove elements: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/remove/

Student Code:

```
class Student {
std::string name; 
int id; 
public:
void setValues(std::string, int); 
std::string getName();
};

void Student::setValues(std::string n, int i)
{
name = n; 
id = i; 
};

std::string Student::getName()
{
    return name; 
}
```

Full Course code:

```
class Course 
{
std::string title; 
std::list<Student> classList; //This is a List that students can be added to. 
std::list<Student>::iterator it; 

public: 
void setValues(std::string); 
void addStudent(Student student);
void dropStudent(Student student);
void printRoster();
};
void Course::setValues(std::string t)
{
    title = t;  
};

void Course::addStudent(Student student)
{
    classList.push_back(student); 
}

void Course::dropStudent(Student student)
{
    classList.remove(student);
}

void Course::printRoster()
{
    for (it=roster.begin(); it!=roster.end(); ++it)
    {
        std::cout << (*it).getName() << " "; 
    }
}
```

Comment: We are going to need more detail.  We don't even know what type of object classList is, or what the remove function looks like.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have edited my doc. Hopefully it is more clear.

Comment: Please post the exact error messages -- do not describe them.  Also we also need to see what `Student` consists of.   If `classList` is a `std::list`, then `remove()` requires that `Student` requires an equality operator (`operator ==`)

Comment: Pass those students and strings by const reference or you copy them lots of times.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The issue is, as pointed out, that `Student` is lacking an `operator==` that is required by `std::list::remove`.

```
#include <string>
class Student {
    std::string name; 
    int id; 

public:
    bool operator == (const Student& s) const { return name == s.name && id == s.id; }
    bool operator != (const Student& s) const { return !operator==(s); }
    void setValues(std::string, int); 
    std::string getName();
    Student() : id(0) {}
};
```

Note how both `operator==` and `operator !=` are overloaded.  It is expected that if two objects can be compared with `==`, then `!=` should also be available to be used.  Check how `operator!=` is written in terms of `operator ==`.

Also note that the parameter is passed as a const reference, and the functions themselves are `const`.

Live Example: http://ideone.com/xAaMdB

Comment: Thanks so much Paul! This works! I was starting to work on adding an operator, but then saw your comment. I was close, but not quite. I really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

[`std::list::remove()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/remove) removes all elements in the list that *compare equal* to the element you give. You don't give your definiton of `Student`, but likely you don't have an `operator == ()` method defined so the call to `remove()` cannot work.

Comment: Should I make a compare() method that would use the `operator == ( )` then call that method in my remove(compare())?

Comment: You could, but you could just define a method in the class to compare two `Student` classes - `bool Student::operator == (Student &)` and decide what makes two students equal on that basis

Comment: @user3281388 The `list::remove` will use `==` to compare two objects.  It knows nothing nor will it do anything wth your `compare()` function.  If you want to write a `compare()` function to be used by yourself or other functions, then that's a different story.

Answer (score 2):

The list can't delete your student cause it can't know how to compare the students in the list to the one given to the `remove` method.
*Note* that the student is passed by value and therefore is a different instance than the one in the list.

One thing you can do is implement an `operator==` in `Student` which will help the list **find** your student.

Another possibility (especially relevant if you can't change `Student` class) will be to hold a list of `Student*` (Student pointer), and then the list will be able to compare the pointers, and find the one you're trying to remove.

Comment: Is it best to create a separate method of the `operator==` or would it be okay put it inside my remove method?

Comment: the `operator==` should be a part of the `Student` class. Usually it's being implemented outside the class though. check out [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators) link.

Comment: Thanks for your think Arnon, that helped me understand what was going on!

Answer (score 0):

```
void Course::dropStudent(Student student)
{
    list<Student>::iterator itr=classList.begin();
    list<Student>temporary;
    while(itr!=classList.end())
    {
        if(itr->id!=student.id)
        {
            temporary.push_back(itr);
        }
        itr++;
    }
    classList=temporary;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Can you please edit your answer to elaborate it a little bit? Like what op was doing wrong, and how you fixed it!